# Is it possible to run CASE WHEN with pre queried data

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, case

I was wondering if it is possible to get the count of a query, plus check if a entity within the query exists at the same time.

So I was looking to do something like this

```
SELECT
    COUNT(a.*)
    CASE WHEN ? IN (a.column) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS exist
    FROM a
    WHERE ...
```

I know I could do a sub-query in the CASE, but is it possible to do it with just the data from the initial query?

---

EDIT

ie

```
+------------+
| id  column |
+------------+
| 1   5      |
| 2   6      |
| 3   7      |
| 4   8      |


SELECT
    COUNT(a.*)
    CASE WHEN 7 IN (a.column) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS exist
    FROM a
    WHERE id > 1
```

Would return

```
+--------------------+
| COUNT(*)     exist |
+--------------------+
| 3             1    |
```

Because there are 3 entries with an id > 1 and within the entries and there is an entry with column = 7

Comment: Elaborate your question with sample data and sample expected data.

Comment: Sure thing, I added an edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check if a value exists in the column, you can do:

```
SELECT COUNT(*),
       MAX(? = a.column) as value_exists
FROM a
WHERE ...
```

In a numeric context, MySQL treats booleans as integers, with 1 for true and 0 for false.  Hence, this returns true if the value is in any row in the column.  You can use `MIN()` if you want to check if the same value is in *all* the rows.